# How do you write a fortran program to print the sum of all the elements in a square matrix

Tags: matrix, fortran

I have an array like this

```
3 4 5
1 2 3
1 2 3
```

How will I write a Fortran program, to print the sum of all elements in this array.

In the above example the output should be 24.

Comment: `print *, sum([3,4,5,1,2,3,1,2,3]) ; end`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome, please take the [tour] and read ask. Did you try the sum intrinsic functions? What happened? How does your code look like? How is the matrix declared?

Comment: Seems like we have many questions about summing an array in some way, but a simple question "how to sum an array" is so simple that it has not been asked yet. However, from the present state of the question above it is not really clear that it is the actual question.

Comment: Do you have the array in your program already or do you first have to read it from an external file?

Answer (score -1):

One way is to use a nested loop in fortran. Let A(1:n1,1:n2) be the array and a general code for any matrix would be,(I'm assuming you have everything declared n1,n2 as integers; sum as real and A as the appropriate array)

```
n1 = size(A,1)
n2 = size(A,2)
sum = 0.0d0
do i = 1,n1
   do j = 1,n2
      sum = sum + A(i,j)  
   enddo
enddo
print*, 'Sum of elements in array is',sum
```

For a square matrix n1 and n2 is the same number. If saving as .f file, keep in mind fortran77 format when writing the code.

Edit: Simplest would be, as someone correctly pointed out,

```
print*, sum(A)
```

Comment: I wouldn't call that "simple" compared with `print*, sum(a)`.

Comment: @francescalus Yeah, my bad. Edited to reflect 'one way' instead of 'simplest way', which isn't true as you correctly pointed out. I assumed the question was without using intrinsic functions.

Comment: Fortran is column major so it would be faster to interchange the loops (although for such a small matrix the difference will be neglectable).

Comment: In the integer example it looks easy, but one often needs the accumulator to have enough digits to not overflow... that sort of excludes SUM for many cases as that returns the same type as it operates on. The use of MAP/UNION can often be handy in these cases, especially when one is unsure of column major...